# R function to find first indicies where a series increases above multiple of a number

Tags: r, function, sequence

I'd like to make an R function which does a very particular job, and I'm looking to find a more efficient way of doing it.

Basically, I'd like a function

```
indicies<-function(increasing.series, multiple)
```

which picks out the indicies of an increasing series where the value of the series exceeds a multiple of a certain level. So for example, if the input is a vector

```
testvector <- c(0.1, 0.5, 1.7, 2.1, 3.2, 4.5, 6.2, 6.3, 6.4, 7.9, 8.1)
```

the results would be

```
[1] 1  4  6  7 11
```

where it holds that

```
testvector[c(1,4,6,7,11)] == c(0.1, 2.1, 4.5, 6.2, 8.1)
```

so that the function picks out the indicies where the values of the series first exceeds 2 (index 4, value 2.1), 4 (index 6, value 5.6), 6 (index 7, value 6.2) and 8 (index 11, value 8.1). For perspective, I plan on using this to have an easy way to pick weekly / monthly / quarterly series out of a daily time series. I was hoping for a way to run some sort of functional-like aggregate function over the windowed pairs of the input series as implementation, but I'm not sure how to do so succintly. Currently, I've implemented the function in the following much more long-winded manner:

```
indicies<-function(increasing.series, multiple)
{
  # Create matrix with three columns: previous, current and orig.index, yielding
  # the previous and current value corresponding to an index in the original
  # series.
  pairs <- zoo::rollapply(data=increasing.series,width=2,identity)
  pairs <- rbind(c(NA, increasing.series[1]),pairs)
  pairs<-cbind(pairs,1:dim(pairs)[1])
  colnames(pairs) <- c("previous","current","orig.index")

  # This predicate returns true if the indexcorresponding to a row of the above matrix should
  # be included in the output.
  predicate <- function(row)
  {
    first <-  row["previous"]
    second <- row["current"]
    orig.index <- row["orig.index"] 
    firstRemainder <-  first  %% multiple
    secondRemainder <- second %% multiple

    # Include if the previous remainder is larger than the current or if the current timepoint
    # is a whole period in front of the previous.
    return(orig.index == 1 || firstRemainder > secondRemainder || second > first + multiple)
  }

  bool.indicies <- apply(pairs,1,predicate)
  return((1:length(bool.indicies))[bool.indicies])
}
```

Is there a better, shorter, more readable way?

Comment: Isn't this just `sapply(2 * 0:4, function(x) min(which(testvector > x)))` ?

Comment: Or `sapply(2 * 0:4, function(x) which.min(testvector < x))`.

Comment: Those seem to work quite well, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simpler solution:

```
indicies <- function(increasing.series, multiple) {
  multiples <- (0:floor(max(increasing.series)/multiple)) * multiple
  sapply(multiples, function(x) which.max(increasing.series > x))
}
indicies(testvector, 2)
#[1]  1  4  6  7 11
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach:

```
c(1, which( diff( testvector %/% 2)>0) + 1)
```

This does not require defining variables or calling sapply.